# Cannot fill test data into a form with rspec, capybara and selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I'm testing my Ruby on Rails 3.2 App with RSpec, Capybara and Selenium (Used driver: webkit and poltergeist).

I will try testing the following code:

```
scenario 'ask a question', js: true do
  visit group_path(@group, locale: 'en')

  find('#question_subject').set 'A new question'
  find('#question_content').set 'The content of the question'
  find('#question_tag_tokens', visible: false).set @tag.id

  find('#submit').click

  expect(page).to have_content 'A new question'
end
```

But when I try to run the test I will receive the following error:

```
 1) Interact with group ask a question
 Failure/Error: find('#question_subject').set 'A new question'
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError:
   waiting for evaluate.js load failed
 # [remote server] file:///var/folders/gz/svmw_f_n73q9z25trgsp_tnm0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20130806-4190-1l8e4c4/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8360:in `r'
 # [remote server] file:///var/folders/gz/svmw_f_n73q9z25trgsp_tnm0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20130806-4190-1l8e4c4/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:392:in `fxdriver.Timer.prototype.runWhenTrue/g'
 # [remote server] file:///var/folders/gz/svmw_f_n73q9z25trgsp_tnm0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20130806-4190-1l8e4c4/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:386:in `fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify'
 # ./spec/features/groups_spec.rb:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>
```

In the spec_helper.rb file has additional lines for DatabaseCleaner:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
end

config.before(:each) do
  if example.metadata[:js]
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  else
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

I cannot solve this issue. I was trying different drivers for testing javascript: poltergeist and capybara-webkit. But I get the same error. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem by using the `chromedriver` for testing:

1. [Download the chromedriver.](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)
2. In my case I moved the chromedriver executable into `/usr/local/bin/` and added this location to my $PATH variable: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin/;$PATH`
3. Add following lines to your `spec/spec_helper.rb` file ([capybara wiki](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#configuring-and-adding-drivers)):

   Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
     Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
   end

**Update:**

The chromedriver caused a new problem: Not finding the hidden elements. So I installed [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/) and now it all works fine.